# Adding collections to one another

Tags: java, collections

I'm reviewing for a class, and this is an old question:

I need to write a method

```
void addAll(Collection c1, Collection c2);
```

that adds all the elements in c2 to c1.

Could I just do something with addAll? I'm not familiar with it, but it seems like I could write:

```
c1.addAll(c2);
```

Comment: yeah, addAll should work in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that'll work. The boolean returned determines whether the collection has been modified by the call.

[http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

Answer (score 0):

If your task is to write such a method, it may be the case that you are not allowed to use the `addAll` method (since it would be too easy, and you learn not so much). If so, think about how to write it again (read the documentation linked by *kubi* for inspirations).

Comment: Hmm, in that case, do you have any (I suppose purposely less elegant) solutions? I guess one would be to loop through the collection size, adding each element independently.

Comment: Yes, you'll need a loop. For maximum elegancy, try `for(E e : c2)` instead of using an explicit iterator or an array.